# Click at specific item at map image Splinter

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

Case related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812012/click-specific-item-in-image-map-using-selenium-3-webdriver/50044702#50044702). Like at it I try click at one of area. I try to achieve it using python and splinter. I'm not good at it an need Your help.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<title>CS121 SNMP/Web Adapter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lang/lang.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/gxlang.js"></script>
</head>

<frameset cols="216,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
 <frame src="menu.shtml" name="cs_menu" frameborder="0">
 <frameset rows="73,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
  <frame src="status.shtml" name="cs_status" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
  <frame src="default.shtml" name="cs_main" frameborder="0">
 </frameset>
</frameset>
```

now I direct to default.shtml

```
<body class="main">
<h2><script type="text/javascript">_dw("Loading")</script> <a href="/main.shtml">/main.shtml</a> ...</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Next to main.shtml

```
<body class="main">

<img src="load.gif" width="36" height="36" name="ajax" id="ajax" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:10px; z-index:5; border:0; display:none; filter:Alpha(opacity=80, finishopacity=20, style=2);">
<img src="led1.gif" width="16" height="16" name="led1" style="position:absolute; left:98px; top:212px; z-index:3; border:0;">
<img src="led1.gif" width="16" height="16" name="led2" style="position:absolute; left:320px; top:205px; z-index:3; border:0;">
<img src="led1.gif" width="16" height="16" name="led3" style="position:absolute; left:474px; top:205px; z-index:3; border:0;">
<img src="led1.gif" width="16" height="16" name="led4" style="position:absolute; left:573px; top:212px; z-index:3; border:0;">
<img src="led1.gif" width="16" height="16" name="led5" style="position:absolute; left:334px; top:410px; z-index:3; border:0;">
<img src="led1.gif" width="16" height="16" name="led6" style="position:absolute; left:398px; top:266px; z-index:3; border:0;">
<img src="b.png" style="position:absolute; top:8px; left:8px; z-index:1; border:0;" usemap="#cetmap">
<map name="cetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="300,184,496,314" href="main2.shtml" alt="Show Modules" title="Show Modules">
**<area shape="rect" coords="79,195,239,302" href="#" onclick="return toggle_infobox('ac_groups')" alt="Show AC Groups" title="Show AC Groups">**
<area shape="rect" coords="260,226,280,246" href="#" onclick="return toggle_infobox('ac_groups2')" alt="Show AC Groups Transfer Parameters" title="Show AC Groups Transfer Parameters">
<area shape="rect" coords="314,394,478,499" href="#" onclick="return toggle_infobox('dc_groups')" alt="Show DC Groups" title="Show DC Groups">
<area shape="rect" coords="400,344,420,364" href="#" onclick="return toggle_infobox('dc_groups2')" alt="Show DC Groups Transfer Parameters" title="Show DC Groups Transfer Parameters">
<area shape="rect" coords="553,195,718,302" href="#" onclick="return toggle_infobox('phases')" alt="Show Phases" title="Show Phases">
<area shape="rect" coords="514,226,534,246" href="#" onclick="return toggle_infobox('phases2')" alt="Show Phases Transfer Parameters" title="Show Phases Transfer Parameters">
 </map>
```

And i try to click at area with "**"

I was try several things. This is what I got now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from splinter import Browser
from time import sleep
from lxml import html
from random import randrange
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

exitCode = 0
def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
       yield start
       start += step

   with Browser('firefox', headless=True) as browser:
        browser.visit("http://1.1.1.1")
        sleep(22)
        browser.driver.save_screenshot('ups2.png')
        test = browser.find_by_name("cetmap")
        test2 = browser.driver.find_elements_by_cssSelector("body > map:nth-child(9) > area:nth-child(3)")
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", test2)
        sleep(5)
        browser.driver.save_screenshot('ups.png')
        browser.quit()
        exit(0)
```

Comment: Code trials please?

Comment: I editing main post

Comment: Maybe that help with something, when I inspect site, I see grey line at block:
    <map name="cetmap">
    ....grey lines....
    </map>

Answer (score 0):

So, I handle with this problem. So maybe someone will search solution to similarly problem. After some inspect my colleague figure out that this map is a one of three frame. When I focus my script at this particular frame I could "create" my solution. This is solution to this one:

At splinter we got [broswer.execution_sctipt](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/javascript.html) and easily we can implement:

```
b = Broswer('firefox')
b.visit("http://1.1.1.1/main.shtml") #this is addres of my frame

#run script from onclick option

b.execute_script("return toggle_infobox(\'ac_groups2\')")
```

This is solution.