# Is there a selenium function to click on area element with a particular class

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on Selenium with Python. I am quite new to this and I am trying to click on an image which has the following HTML

structure:

HTML:

```html
<div id="result">
   <img class="img-450" usemap="#476872907" src="#" border="0" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" alt="">
   <map name="476872907">
      <area class="cursor" onclick="javascript:Captcha107('6k9frpw1');" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" coords="1,4,63,88">
      <area class="cursor" onclick="javascript:Captcha107('ya3ltbiv');" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" coords="65,4,128,88">
      <area class="cursor" onclick="javascript:Captcha107('9rbukmey');" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" coords="129,4,191,88">
      <area class="cursor" onclick="javascript:Captcha107('5mlv909r');" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" coords="192,4,255,88">
      <area class="cursor" onclick="javascript:Captcha107('eu7idjnz');" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" coords="257,4,319,88">
      <area class="cursor" onclick="javascript:Captcha107('al9a6zih');" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" coords="321,4,384,88">
      <area class="cursor" onclick="javascript:Captcha107('nyvkjeoc');" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" coords="385,4,448,88">
   </map>
</div>
```

I have tried a couple of things, for example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img/@class="img-450"').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//area[@class="cursor"]').click()
```

but, I seem to always end up with errors, for example:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: shape= is not supported
```

or

```
sselenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //img/@class="img-450" because of the following error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
```

I am wondering if I can somehow click on the image using the area element.

Any thoughts which can point me in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Please share relevant HTML clock

Comment: Added the html code

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812012/click-specific-item-in-image-map-using-selenium-3-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML you've shared, You could try this code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
img= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#result>img')))
img.click()
```

Make sure to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: I tried this but encountered the following error:
Element <img class="img-450" usemap="#677005183" src="#" border="0" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" alt=""> is not clickable at point (468, 332). Other element would receive the click: <area class="cursor" onclick="javascript:Captcha107('d1b40ts8');" title="Click on a repeated (mirrored) image bellow" coords="192,4,255,88">

Answer (score 0):

This is solution:

driver.execute_script("javascript:Captcha107('6k9frpw1');")

Use re library for get source page and this code ->('6k9frpw1')